# how do you get one specific term from a shortcode attribute?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I'm working on a function where I just want to output a button that links to a specific term. I have used `get_the_terms` and have gotten it to work successfully, but I've been trying `get_term` and I've have no luck. I want the shortcode to look like this `[see_all_products category="bakery"]` and output a button that links to it.

This is my function so far:

```
function product_category_button($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category'  => '',
    ), $atts));

    // if( $category ) :

        // Vars
        $taxonomy = 'product_categories';
        $term = get_term( $category, $taxonomy ); //$post->ID
        $cat = $term->name;
        $parent = $term->parent;

        var_dump($cat);

        if ($parent == NULL) :

            // Vars
            $link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy);

            $html_out = '';
            $html_out .= '<a class="x-btn x-btn-primary x-btn-global hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="' . $link . '">' . 'See All Products' . $cat . '</a>';
        endif;

        return $html_out;

    // endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'see_all_products', 'product_category_button' );
```

Right now, `$link` gives me this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string" and `$cat` returns `NULL` in the `var_dump`.

Not sure if this could be affecting it, but the `$parent` stuff here was meant to get only the parent term.

Comment: I'm unsure to how to use that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get a term by it's slug or name. `get_term()` will get all the term's data by it's *id*. In this case, use `get_term_by()` instead:

```
function product_category_button($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category'  => '',
    ), $atts));

    // if( $category ) :

        // Vars
        $taxonomy = 'product_categories';
        // Use 'name' instead of 'slug' if you want to get the term by it's name
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug' , $category, $taxonomy ); //$post->ID
        $cat = $term->name;
        $parent = $term->parent;

        var_dump($cat);

        if ($parent == NULL) :

            // Vars
            $link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy);

            $html_out = '';
            $html_out .= '<a class="x-btn x-btn-primary x-btn-global hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="' . $link . '">' . 'See All Products' . $cat . '</a>';
        endif;

        return $html_out;

    // endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'see_all_products', 'product_category_button' );
```

For further reading, take a look into [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).

Answer (score 0):

### use

[get_category_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) and [get_category_by_slug](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_by_slug/)

```
function product_category_button($atts) {

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'category_slug'  => '',
  ), $atts));

  // if( $category_slug) :
          $get_category = get_category_by_slug($category_slug);

          $link = get_category_link($get_category);

          $html_out = '';
          $html_out .= '<a class="x-btn x-btn-primary x-btn-global hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="' . $link . '">' . 'See All Products' . $get_category->name. '</a>';


      return $html_out;

  // endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'see_all_products', 'product_category_button' );
```